# INSERT a row only if @@hostname equals a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, hostname

Is it possible to use a `WHERE` clause somehow (or *any* other way) in an `INSERT` query so it only works if the `@@hostname` variable is a certain value? For example:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
    (field_1, field_2)
VALUES
    ('foo', 'bar')
WHERE @@hostname = 'url.to.host.here';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: @@hostname is the MySQL hostname.

You can invalid a select query like this because the MySQL optimizer sees this as an impossible `WHERE`.

```
SELECT
   'field_1'
 , 'field_2'
FROM
  DUAL
WHERE 0;
```

MySQL has an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query so when you use:

```
INSERT INTO
   table_name (
     field_1
   , field_2
  )
  SELECT
      'field_1'
    , 'field_2'
   FROM
     DUAL
   WHERE 0
```

The INSERT INFO will not be executed.

When you use:

```
INSERT INTO
   table_name (
     field_1
   , field_2
  )
  SELECT
      'field_1'
    , 'field_2'
   FROM
     DUAL
   WHERE 1;
```

The `INSERT INTO` will be executed. See demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5623f/1

With the @@hostname check:

```
INSERT INTO
   table_name (
     field_1
   , field_2
  )
  SELECT
      'field_1'
    , 'field_2'
   FROM
     DUAL
   WHERE IF(
     @@hostname = 'ip-10-0-0-15'
     , 1
     , 0
   );
```

See demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9081/4.

As a sidenote you can also use this to "support" CHECK (MySQL doesn't support CHECK with CREATE TABLE statement) on columns normally you need triggers to do this.

See demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dfa2/1.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
IF (STRCMP(@@hostname, 'url.to.host.here') = 0) THEN
    INSERT INTO table_name
        (field_1, field_2)
    VALUES ('foo', 'bar')
END IF
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work: `[ERROR in query 1] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(@@hostname='foobar')` (hostname hidden for security reasons)

Comment: Still doesn't work. Same syntax error, near `IF (STRCMP(...` :(

Comment: I imagine the `IF` only works in stored procedures, and I assume the OP is only executing general SQL? So, one solution is to call a stored proc to do this - or to use application-side logic.

Comment: @halfer IF statement do work in normal sql check mine answer check the part "With the @@hostname check" Note IF statements are not limited to be used only in the WHERE statement

Comment: @Raymond: are you saying that the `IF` in this answer would run outside of a stored procedure, as it stands? (Good answer elsewhere, btw).